Static files not served in Django production
My Django application working perfectly on my local machine but when I successfully deployed it to AWS EC2, I don't get any styling. I tried search for solution as many others faced this issue but non of the answers fixed my case. I tried a lot of stuff for two days but nothing seem to work with me. What am I missing or doing wrong?
Appreciate your help!
These are my folders:
enter image description here
This is my settings.py file:
import dj_database_url
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Django Apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # My Apps
    'main_app.apps.MainAppConfig'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    # My Middleware
    'main_app.middleware.LoginCheckMiddleWare',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'student_management_system.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['main_app/templates'], #My App Templates
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# WSGI_APPLICATION = 'student_management_system.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'student_management_system.asgi.application'


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
# MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "mediafiles"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"


I tried using whitenoise by following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/OeywgMArAGM?si=2FDaKy4GmT3GLDVA
I tried following some answers from StackOverflow but none worked with me

use nginx? or other?

yeah, use nginx to server static files
